# How to access a function from another class - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I have this function called `getTextColor` but I've had to declare it in another class. How do I access this function from a different class?

Here is how I'm trying to access it:

```
class _NextPageState extends State<NextPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(children: [
              TextSpan(
                  text: widget.result + '  ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: getTextColor(widget.result), // Here is the problem.
                    height: 2.5,
                    letterSpacing: 0.7,
                  )),
```

The function's logic is inside a class called `class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen>`

**To sum up,** how do I tell the code that `getTextColor` is from the other class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create object of another clas or make the function static in order to access it.
If the function is static then you can call it like this:

```
ClassName.getTextColor();
```

If the function is not static then you need to create an object to call it like this:

```
var object = ClassName();
object.getTextColor();
```

Comment: Just to make sure, the object should be declared inside the class from the code above, right?

Comment: Hello bilbo_bo, the object can be declared before @override widget build.